# Форма с выбором огромного числа элементов

Tags: javascript, php, html, веб-программирование

Столкнулся с проблемой с предоставлением возможности пользователю выбрать значение из огромного списка элементов.
Пользователь в обычной форме может выбрать интересующее его значение, но проблема в том, что значения подгружаются из бд и количество элементов около 5000. На ум приходит какой-нибудь select с возможностью поиска по значению, но браузер умрет, отрисовывая все эти 5000 .
Интересует как в таком случае правильно предоставить возможность выбора для пользователя в форме, если элементов очень много?

Comment: "но php или js умрут отрисовывая все эти 5000 ." — этот вот текст что значит, поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Наверно все таки неправильно выразился. Умрет браузер отрисовывая 5000 optionо.  php или hs скорее всего будут просто довольно долго обрабатывать эти элементы

Comment: гуглить живой поиск, реализаций примерно миллион

Comment: @qwabra как минимум потому что вопрос был в том, как правильно представить, а не пример поиска на заявление "js умрет" ? Вопрос был не в том, умрет ли он.

Comment: @krown_loki, вы нашли "живой поиск" из совета выше, разобрались как он работает? если нет - поищите и сравните с моим примером. ха, да! коммент выше был дан после моего ответа, если что

Comment: @qwabra вы не видите разницу в том, что в вашем скрипте 5000 значений (не говоря о том, что сами значения в рабочем варианте, это не просто последовательность интов) хранятся в памяти, а в совете выше результаты предполагается рисовать в дропбоксе, размер которого будет ограничиваться запросом пользователя в момент времени?

Comment: @krown_loki, "последовательность интов" говорите? - вам туда https://learn.javascript.ru/ и напоследок - откройте для себя IDE например вставьте кода вот сюда http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?useJavaScript=true#code/FBA

Comment: @qwabra и при чем здесь обучалка js к последовательности интов? Вас смутило слово "инт", которым я обозначил цифры и вы пытаетесь пояснить за динамическую типизацию?
Ваш код я уже попробовал здесь. Как открытие IDE или другого ресурса с целью "попробовать код" отменяет тот факт, что в памяти остается массив с огромным числом элементов в вашем примере?

Comment: вы не знаете JS, IDE вам поможет

Comment: @qwabra давайте конкретику. Вопросы выше комментом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильней всего будет сделать подгрузку результатов, релевантных тому, что ввводит пользователь, посредством ajax. То есть на сервере у вас некий скрипт, принимающий строку поиска, ищет результаты, отдает их в виде json, а на клиенте обычный текст инпут, куда пользователь вводит поисковое слово. Результаты поиска подгружаются под инпутом с возможностью выбора. Примерно как в Гугле это происходит. Посмотрите в сторону js библиотеки select2, она умеет делать такой дропбокс из коробки.

Answer (score -2):

> js умрёт

просто пример поиска на JS

```js
// @ts-check
const dataList = Array.from({ length: 5000 }, (q, i) => '' + i)

/** @param {string} str*/
const genOption = str => {
    const option = document.createElement('option')
    option.value = str
    option.innerHTML = str
    return option
}
const select = document.createElement('select')
const input = document.createElement('input')
input.type = 'text'
input.placeholder = '123'
input.oninput = _.debounce(oninput, 150)
document.body.append(input, select)

/** @param {Event} q*/
function oninput(e) {
    const { value } = input
    const list = searchQ(dataList, value)
    const optionList = list.map(genOption)
    select.innerHTML = ''
    select.append(...optionList)
}

/**
 * @param {string[]} dataList
 * @param {string} value
 */
function searchQ(dataList, value) {
    return dataList.filter(val => val.includes('' + value)).splice(0, 10)
}
```

```html
<script src="http://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>
```

Comment: *удивительный* по своей нерелевантности ответ

Comment: хз,хз - никогда не знаешь что автор вкладывает в вопрос

Comment: @qwabra Всегда понятно, если вопрос корректно и ясно написан.

Comment: очень много если, давайте конкретику, есть вопрос - что скажете?